# SharePoint Weather Forecast (weekly)

Tags: sharepoint, widget

All,

I am looking to embed a weather widget on my sharepoint page (modern). Does anyone have any solution BESIDES the weather webpart? The weather webpart only shows today's forecast, but I need to show a 7 day forecast. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**The Weather web part**, which allows you to show the current weather on your page.

If your want see more weather information, click the **MSN weather** link to go to the MSN site.

[image]

[image]

For more information, please see the "**[Show the weather on your page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-the-weather-on-your-page-4a86540e-0846-4fc0-bad0-1a82fcd430fc)**".